# 'For Each' If Statement Loop Issues

Tags: vba, excel, loops

*This is for Excel's VBA
This is probably just a stupid logic error on my part but I've been working on this for hours and I just can't seem to figure it out:

I have a webpage with two links I need to access. These two links are changing daily, but always have the same beginning sequence (Example.... Google websites almost always begin with "http://www.google.com")

I have the code to search through all "a" HTML tags for links that have certain text in them (like "google"). **If** the link is found, I need to click the link, then **go back** (via objIE.Back) and **continue the loop sequence without resetting**. It is this last part that I am having trouble with. My code grabs the first link it see's, does what I want it to do, goes back, *but then it doesn't seem to remember that it already handled the first link* and it just keeps repeating the finding of that first link.

Can anyone take a look at what I have and tell me where I went wrong?
Edit: I have updated this with my current code with the stupid loop and "End For" deleted. Same thing is happening though. Where did I go wrong?

```
Sub Button17_Click()
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim OrgBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim ticketnumber As String
Dim Error As String
Dim subaccnum As String
Dim IEURL As String
Dim button As Object
Dim ele As Object
Dim NodeList As Object
Dim tagName As Object
Dim elementid As Object
Dim Tag As Object
Dim hrefvalue As String
Dim hrefurlvalue As String
Dim trimedhrefvalue As String
Dim ieLinks As Object
Dim Links As Object
Dim ieAnchors As Object
Dim Anchor As Object
Dim I As Integer



Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A5").Value = ""
Range("A9").Value = ""
subaccnum = Range("A2").Value
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.StatusBar = "Opening Internet Explorer"
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.navigate "http://www.youtube.com" ' This is just a test website as my website is under a private VPN and cannot be accessed by anyone but me. Website should not effect loop though
    objIE.Visible = True 'False
     Application.StatusBar = "Loading website..."
    Do While objIE.readyState < 4: Loop

Set objIE2 = Nothing
'Call Wait
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))




 Application.StatusBar = "Trying to find link..."
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
        'objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "execute('RefreshList');"
        Set ieLinks = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

        For Each Links In ieLinks
            If Links.outerHTML Like "<A href=""javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId=*" Then
                'Links.Click
                Application.StatusBar = "Found link! Please wait"
                Links.Value = hrefvalue
                trimedhrefvalue = Right(Links, 49)
                hrefurlvalue = "http://www.youtube.com" & trimedhrefvalue
                objIE.navigate hrefurlvalue

 Do While objIE.readyState < 4: Loop
'Call Wait
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.StatusBar = "Extracting Email From Server..."
IEURL = objIE.LocationURL
'Range("A12").Value = IEURL
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Activate
Rows("1:500").Delete
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;" & IEURL, _
        Destination:=Range("a2"))

.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = False
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = False
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = "Adding Data to spreadsheet..."

Cells.Find(What:="Email Address", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:= _
        xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Sheets("Import").Select
        If ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset = 1).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset = 1).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset = 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 objIE.GoBack
 Do While objIE.readyState < 4: Loop
 'Call Wait
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:4"))

Application.StatusBar = "Searching for 2nd account owner..."

           End If
        Next Links

End Sub
```

Possible workaround:

```
For i = 1 To ieLinks.Length
            If ieLinks.Item(i).outerHTML Like "<A href=""javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId=*" Then
                'Links.Click


Application.StatusBar = "Found link! Please wait"
            ieLinks.Item(i).Value = hrefvalue
            trimedhrefvalue = Right(ieLinks.Item(i), 49)
            hrefurlvalue = "http://www.youtube.com" & trimedhrefvalue
            objIE.navigate hrefurlvalue
            .....................
Next i
```

EDIT: TEMPORARY SOLUTION FOUND
In the end, I never did get that link to work. What I did was that I assigned the ieLinks.Item(i) to a random range on the spreadsheet (somewhere nobody will ever scroll to). Once the links are here, they remain static. Then I just made a simple "For each Cell in rng" loop to run through each link until the end. 
This is not what I originally set out to do, nor is it an exact answer to this question, but it is a temporary solution that makes the modification of the links much easier than keeping the links in VBA's memory.

Comment: You realize that you are exiting the for loop at the bottom ("Exit For"). This is jumping out of the for loop (and never going to the next one). Then you have a "Loop" statement (although the code you provided doesn't show what you are looping back to), which is presumably starting the whole thing over again.

Comment: You should consider indenting the code to match your code blocks, like if statements, loops, etc. it's incredibly hard to read the code the way you've posted it.

Comment: Not sure why it was copied and pasted that way. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the "Exit For" line and it should go to the next one.

You haven't included all of the code, as this all seems to appear within some other loop (judging by the "Loop" statement at the bottom that doesn't have a matching "Do WHile" or other loop structure.  You may be looping forever depending on what is happening in that loop.

******EDIT****

The second problem I see is in this part of the code:

```
      If Links.outerHTML Like "<A href=""javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId=*" Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Found link! Please wait"
            Links.Value = hrefvalue
            trimedhrefvalue = Right(Links, 49)
            hrefurlvalue = "http://www.youtube.com" & trimedhrefvalue
            objIE.navigate hrefurlvalue

            ......
```

Here, you are setting "Links.Value" to hrefvalue, which hasn't been initialized, so it is an empty string.  When trying to test this, it wouldn't even let me change this value and threw an error, but assuming that it does, you are setting the value to "", then getting the right 49 characters of it and appending it to the website.  This would seem to keep opening the same website....

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The spreadsheet is actually at work so I can't look at this until tomorrow morning to test it. Yes, the loop did just endlessly repeat the macro until I stopped the code myself. I had a "Do Events" statement at the top but took it out because I thought it was irrelevant (Just forgot to take out the loop too!)
I will vote on this answer tomorrow.

Comment: I just wanted to give an update on this one:
I will update the OP to include my whole code because something isn't working. I deleted the Loop as well as the "Exit For" but the same thing is happening... Just keeps grabbing the same link over and over again on repeat.

Comment: I made a simple loop where I just debug.printed links.outerhtml and it looped through all of the ielinks on the test website I did.  My guess is that you are somehow resetting the value of Links somewhere.  You could try making a very simple loop through ieLinks and then slowly adding the rest of the code in to see where it is getting stuck.

Comment: Regarding your edited answer, I'm not sure what to change that into then. I take my code to mean set the variable 'hrefvalue' equal to the value of the current variable 'Links'. If I change the Links.Value, I don't get an error but the code just doesn't run correctly and just brings me to the main website page every time since the trimedhrefvalue becomes "" since it was not set to the value of Links. I hope that makes sense. When I Debug.Print my Links at various points in the code it is always the same. Not sure where it could be resetting. Stepping through seems to work as expected

Comment: If I Debug.Print the "hrefvalue" right after I set Links.Value = hrefvalue, I get "javascript:fnOpenWindow('/ao/party/popuppartyinfo?partyId=111111&nav=off')" which is correct

Comment: Update: Could the problem be that the page navigates to a different page and then uses the ObjIE.Back command to go back to the first page it scanned the links on? Maybe that navigation resets the Links back to (0). Is there a way to save the original Links list to a variable that does not change so that the links are not reset?

Comment: Try changing your loop to: "For i = 1 To ielinks.length.....Next i" and then change "Links" to "ieLinks.Item(i)" and see what happens.

Comment: Won't be able to try this until tomorrow. I just updated the bottom of my OP. Is that how you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  It should at least give you some more information about what's going on (and might even work if the issue is related to the objie.back command).

Comment: Just wanted to provide an update on this:
I changed the code to use 'i' instead of "Links" and I crossed my fingers as much as I could. No luck though - same thing happens. It just repeats the first link import instead of moving on to the second. But this is progress as I think it proves that it has something to do with the page navigating away from the source and then back to it. Is there a way to save the list of links as an unchanging variable outside of the loop and then having the code read from that variable? Something like "Set List_of_Links = ieLinks? Any thoughts?

Comment: The "i" method makes navigating away from the source irrelevant.  Is "i" getting incremented?  Perhaps the same link appears in ieLinks several times.  What is ieLinks.count?  What if you did a loop that solely output ielinks.item(i).outerhtml?  Are the links different then?

Comment: Updated OP with my solution. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know. I'm still convinced it had to do with the page navigation but setting the links to a cell range was an effective way to circumvent this issue